# Temporarily - Adverb Placement

Tags: adverb-placement

Where should adverb **temporarily** be placed in English?

> **A can temporarily display B** versus **A can display temporarily B**

> **A can temporarily function** versus **A can function temporarily**

I am confused because after a long search of the usage frequency in New York Times, both usages seem possible.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't say _A can display temporarily B_ because it separates the verb from its object - but you could say _A can display B temporarily_.  Putting the word near the beginning of the sentence puts more emphasis on it, that's all.

Comment: Thank you. How about *A can temporarily display B*?

Comment: I meant to imply that all your other versions are fine - as I say, it's just the writer's choice whether to put the word near the beginning of the sentence or at the end.

Comment: Understood, thank you. So in the cases of *A can temporarily function* and *A can function temporarily*, both versions are fine since there is no object? Is there a more idiomatic one? Apologies for the questions, but adverb placement is not intuitive at all for a non-native speaker...

Comment: They don't sound like complete sentences to me; I would expect _function as XXX_ or _A can function only temporarily_ where _only_ emphasises that it isn't permanent.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe *function* is an inappropriate verb for our purposes. Let us take *work* instead. Would adverb placement be ok in the following example? *There is growing medical consensus that transplants can work temporarily.* And how about the following alternative? *There is growing medical consensus that transplants can temporarily work.*

Comment: Here again, I would expect _can work only temporarily_, since we expect an organ transplant to be a long-term solution. How about _You can temporarily store your things in my shed_ or _You can store your things in my shed temporarily_, both of which are valid.

Comment: Thank you. How about this? *Some trasplants can work temporarily but no permanent cure has been found.* In this case it would be inappropriate to include *only*. Would the sentence be ok with *temporarily* after the verb?

Comment: That's fine, but _temporarily work_ would sound odd in this case.